# UEFI Boot settings in User Application

Tags: operating-system, bios, sys, uefi

I see that UEFI provides an API so that some of the boot variables can be available to the user space. One of them is the efivarfs.  I am trying to understand if these are the boot configs that are also available in the BIOS Menu of the OS or these have additional variables that one can manipulate even if these are not present in the boot menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EFI variables are generic variables, purpose of these variable is to store the information persistently across the reboot.

EFI variables can be boot variables or it can be anything which user can use during the boottime and runtime.

e.g;
I can define a variable X(with some (GUID), and I can take the different boot path during early boot process.

```
if (x == 1)
    boot normally;
else if(x==2)
    boot restricted mode;
else if (x==)
    boot without network cads;
else 
    boot without network and iocards;
```

NOTE that x is not the boot variable, and not showing in BIOS menu.

Comment: What about the EFI runtime variables( I mean the ones we can modify from the user level?) How do we know what values these should be to change some feature in the firmware? All these runtime variables seem to have different names on different systems based on the OEM. I thought these are generic ones across platforms specified by UEFI...

Comment: UEFI spec defines some variable(both boot time and run time), which are generic and all platform which are adhere to UEFI must implement these variables, Apart from these variable user can define there own variable. 
'dmpstore' command in UEFI shell will display all UEFI variables.